# Unexpected Error Braintree (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Getting this error while using braintree sdk for Nodejs (v14.15.0) on a local machine (Win 10 x64).

[image]

Here is the minimal code:

```
private constructor(merchantId: string, publicKey: string, privateKey: string, env?: braintree.Environment) {
    this._gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
        merchantId,
        publicKey,
        privateKey,
        environment: env
    });
}

async CreateCustomer(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string): Promise<BraintreeCreateCustomerResponse> {
    let data = await this._gateway.customer.create({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email
    });
    return { Id: data.customer.id };
}
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. Were you able to solve it? The only answer given below is useless!

Answer (score 0):

As per the Type Definitions for braintree, you'll have to provide a configuration of the environment you are using, so this:

```
private constructor(merchantId: string, publicKey: string, privateKey: string, env?: braintree.Environment)
```

becomes this:

```
private constructor(merchantId: string, publicKey: string, privateKey: string, env?: braintree.Environment.Sandbox)
```

You can choose any of the following:

> Development, Production, Qa, Sandbox

I'm not entirely sure if this will help. But, it's worth a try.